# \hat Causes double superscript

Tags: errors, superscripts

I have the following:

```
 {{\hat{\pi}}^a}^b
```

Everything is grouped, so it should behave fine, but it causes a double superscript error, same is true for `{\hat{\pi}^a}^b`. if I remove the `\hat` every thing works, even if I add a `\bar`:

```
{{\hat{\bar{\pi}}}^a}^b
```

Everything works.
Removing the last superscript `{{\hat{\pi}}^a}` also works.
Cant find the reason the first line breaks.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$ {{}\hat{\pi}^a}^b$
\end{document}
```

This is caused by an primitive feature of tex's treatment of math lists that just consist of an accent node essentially losing one level of grouping.

Comment: Thanks! works now.